# How to make transparent text to jpeg?

Tags: php, image, gif

Everywhere is talking about adding text on transparent image. I have successfully added text like watermark (so mean transparent text). Can you suggest me how to give opacity 50% ?

Here is code -

```
$text = "GIF-KING";
$font = "arial.ttf";

$image = imagecreatefromgif('tmpimg/myimage.gif');
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 198, 60, 147);
//imagestring($image,36, 10, 20,  $text, $text_color);

imagettftext($image, 30, 0,10, 290, $text_color, $font, $text);
```

Comment: Set the image 50% opacity or the text?

Comment: take a look http://www.sitepoint.com/watermarking-images/

Comment: `imagecolorallocatealpha`?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need `imagecolorallocatealpha` instead of `imagecolorallocate`,
alpha blending is not available 100%, so take care of error messages.

> imagecolorallocatealpha() behaves identically to imagecolorallocate()
>   with the addition of the transparency parameter alpha.

http://php.net/imagecolorallocatealpha